# Using interop constructor in map function(Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I am getting this complaint when passing Integer constructor to map function :

```
=> (map Integer. ["1" "2" "3"])
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Integer., compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

However when I wrap the constructor in a function everything works:

```
=> (defn str-to-int [str] (Integer. str))
=> (map str-to-int ["1" "2" "3"])
(1 2 3)
```

Why do I have to wrap Integer in another function to make this work? Is there a better way to make it work without creating additional function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map takes in a function and interop uses a special forms like new . and .. 
It is fairly easy to wrap these with anonymous function literals

for example

```
(map #(Integer. %) ["1" "2" "3"])
```

produces the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

without java interop.  if you just need to convert to digits.

```
; nrepl.el 0.2.0 (Clojure 1.5.1, nREPL 0.2.3)
user> (map read-string ["1" "2"])
(1 2)
user> (class (first *1))
java.lang.Long
```

Or if you really need Integer class

```
user> (map (comp int read-string) ["1" "2"])
(1 2)
user> (class (first *1))
java.lang.Integer
```